# When executed simultaneously with other multiple SPs, the stored procedure takes a long time to process. Can the process be improved in any way?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, stored-procedures, database-performance

For an analytics dashboard page, multiple network requests are sent to API to create graphs and charts which causes multiple stored procedures getting executed concurrently. Some of these Sps take about 40 seconds to run, however if they are run separately, they run in about 3-5 seconds?

What might be causing the slow performance, and are there any possible solutions to enhance it?

I evaluated the SP's performance with less network queries, and while the performance was improved ,but the network requests can't be reduced more.

Comment: Try run this blocking chain script https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/04/20/sql-server-blocking-tree-identifying-blocking-chain-using-sql-scripts/ while the queries are runnig. It's possible one of the queries is blocking all the others. When you have identified which one is the issue, please show us the relevant procedures, and their tables and index definitions, and please share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan In the meantime there is little else we can help you with.